# Sliding up Animation but wrap_content

Tags: android, animation, slide

What I want to achieve is the XML (**no code please!!!**) to do this:
[image]

I don't want the xml below because it drag my popup window to the top of screen

```
    <translate 
    android:fromYDelta="100%p" 
    android:toYDelta="0%p" 
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:duration="500" />
```

Here's my XML but it doesn't work either :(

```
    <translate 
    android:fromYDelta="100%p" 
    android:toYDelta="-100%"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:duration="500" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very simple to do if you have any experience with animation!

You'll need to create a folder in your /res folder called anim, and inside of that folder put the slide_up.xml animation file:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:fromYDelta="100%"
        android:toYDelta="0%"       
        android:duration="1000" />
</set>
```

And then a slide_down.xml animation file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toYDelta="100%"
        android:duration="1000" />
</set>
```

Then you'll have in your java where you create your fragment:

```
String FRAGMENT_TAG = "YOURFRAGMENT"; //this is how you'll look for it in the manager
YourFragment f = new YourFragment();
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
         .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_up,
                R.anim.slide_down)              
         .replace(R.id.menu_container, f, FRAGMENT_TAG)
         .addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

Or if you are using a popup window:

```
popupwindow.showAtLocation(getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.‌​content), Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 0);
```

And voila! I'm not quite sure of a way to do this through xml only. This seems to be one of the easier ways that is fairly flexible.

Comment: Sorry for my late reply... I believe that there's a typo in your slide_up.xml. It should be android:fromYDelta="100%" (not negative number). I tried :) The slide_down.xml is correct. And secondly, I find out that it's important to add this code:
  popupwindow.showAtLocation(getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content), Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 0); (I just have to initialize popupwindow and tell it where to show. I don't use fragment :) )

So +1 for the code presentation and the idea but please edit your answer a little bit so I can check it as an accepted answer. Thanks :)

Comment: I added the two things you mentioned. Sorry about the wrong value - my sliding is done from the top down so I had to change them without trying the new values! I also added the line you mentioned. I've never done it that way - hopefully I edited it correctly :)

Comment: I didn't use any fragment and I don't really think it's neccessary for popup window. So please leave it. Just keep your 2 XMLs and my code. That's enough. Thanks :)

Comment: That's it. Nothing more :)